# api для андроид приложения

Tags: android, mysql, api

есть несколько вопросов по поводу API:

1. Как написать API для андроид приложения, чтобы соединить с mysql базой, с которой соединен сам сайт;
2. допустим я написал API, и куда её дальше класть или вставить

Comment: никуда. обращаться к нему из приложения.

Comment: так мне надо написать и вставить написанный API в приложении?

Comment: что значит вставить в приложение? Приложение ваше должно этот API использовать, отправлять к нему запросы. получать ответы, преобразовывать в нужный вид использовать.

Comment: ну тогда где должна находиться API? и как указать его место, в приложении

Comment: По сути это серверное приложение, которое в ответ на запросы определённого формата будет возвращать данные. Можете посмотреть здесь простейший пример: [Создание простейшего REST API](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html)

Comment: значит API должен находиться в папке с сайтом? который лежит на сервере?

Answer (score 2):

Создаете скрипт, отдающий json или что вы там отдаете, помещаете его куда вам удобно, например site.com/api/api.php и из приложения обращаетесь по этому url